# Ordering cell values according to cell number

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sequence, flatten, nested-if

I have some data spread through different cells. Some cells have comma separated values.
I have included an example that can be seen in the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G7pMTYlYDEKx_TiuSfvhJZprYaHnFRY-DRq-e1B834I/edit?usp=sharing).

I need to match the data with cell number and show them in the results section as in the example sheet.

How can I achieve this outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(REPT(
 IF(A2:O3="",,A1:O1&"×"), LEN(IFERROR(
 REGEXREPLACE(A2:O3, "[0-9]+", )))+1)),,9^9)), "×"))
```

[image]